# Jquery selector in TR

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

If I got something like this :

```
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr class="sub" id="2">2</tr>
<tr class="sub" id="3">3</tr>
<tr class="sub" id="4">4</tr>
<tr class="main"></tr>
<tr class="sub" id="6">6</tr>
<tr class="sub" id="7">7</tr>
<tr class="main" id="8">8</tr>
<tr class="sub"></tr>
```

Using JQUERY selectors, is there a way, when I'm on a TR with the sub class, to get only the others TR.sub between the TR.main before et the TR.main after ?

For example, if I'm on the TR.sub with 3, how can I get the TR.sub with 2, 3 and 4 with JQUERY ? (between previous main and next main).

I can get the previous TR.main with (example for the TR with id="3") :

```
$("#3").prevAll("tr.main:first")
```

So I need to get all these 3 TR :

```
<tr class="sub" id="2">2</tr>
<tr class="sub" id="3">3</tr>
<tr class="sub" id="4">4</tr>
```

Comment: That's invalid `tr` html.

Comment: If you got something like this, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: it's an example, I didn't put all the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) is what you're after:

```
$("#3").prevAll("tr.main:first").nextUntil("tr.main")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the following:

```
.prevUntil('.main');

.nextUnti('.main');
```

**Note**: Please avoid the following problematic HTML:

```
- tr elements with non td children
- elements with numeric id values.
```

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    var target = $('#i3');
    var all = target.add( target.prevUntil('.main') ).add( target.nextUntil('.main') );
    console.log( all );
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/x4hQF/)

Comment: Sure, It's just an example :) I will try this, thanks

Comment: Ok, I understand. I have just put a demo together and added code to show how you might use the two.